# Android github push and pull

Tags: android, git, github

First time using git and github for my small android project that I will be the base user. The rest of the team will have to submit a  `pull request` for me to review.

I created a project and have the others forked the project. When I committed and pushed new content to my repo and notify my team members to update their copy.
They clicked the blue down arrow on android studio but they can't seems to be able to update by pulling from me? It just says the "All files are up to date".

They are also not able to push. `"Failed with error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/groupmemberusername/project.git/': The requested URL returned error : 403"`

From my understanding is that a `pull request` is something for you to notify the original base repo creator(which is me) to review and thus decide whether to merge the changes to the original repo. Is this understanding wrong?

Comment: do you have access to read/write?

Comment: Your understanding of a pull request is correct. Perhaps [this article](https://help.github.com/articles/https-cloning-errors/) may help you with Error 403.

Comment: @tony not sure how do you test that, but I as the original creator are able to push and pull from android studio

Answer (score 1):

Here is the steps to create pull request

1. git checkout -b "sub_branch_name_created from base branch"
2. git add Foo.java
3. git commit -m "message"
4. git push origin "sub_branch_name_created from base branch"

Now open gitHub and there would be your commit listed, click on it there you can see a button named "New pull Request" click on that, then all you have to do is select the base branch and the branch you just created.

That's it.[image: <code>[![enter image description here][1]][1]</code>]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. a `pull request`is issued by the owner of a `fork` (clone) from the original project (or from a separate `branch`of the original project), to inform the project owner/leader, that someone has made a change, that should be reviewed.

---

Generally, there are 2 options, where a pull request can be made.

### Same project, different branch

One project can have different branches.
Example: You (the project owner) control the `master`branch. Your team members have no writing permissions for the `master`branch, but they can create a branch, where they have full access (e.g. `projectname-membername`). The code modified in the separate branch are not reflected in the `master` branch.

In this case, your members should doublecheck, if they are pushing/pulling from/to the `master` branch, they might not have the permissions to read/write.

### Different project (fork)

In your specific case, your team members created a `fork`, a separate project, copying the codebase of the original project (called `upstream`).

Without having full-access to the `upstream` project, your members have full-access to their fork, which can be merged with the `upstream` project after you reviewed it (`pull request`).

Your members should doublecheck, that they are `push`ing to their own fork, not the `upstream` project. Please note, that they should `pull` from their own fork (working on another computer, for example), and do a pull request to get their changes into the `upstream` project.

Edit: If you make changes to the `upstream` project, your members have to `fetch` the changes from `upstream` and do a manual `merge` with their local changes.

Comment: @On the part of if I(owner) make changes to the `upstream` project. My members have to pull changes from `upstream`. Right now whenever I write changes to the `upstream` project. They have to go to their forked repo and submit a pull request and approve it, only then will their forked repo update to the updated `upstream` version. That seems a little weird to me?

Comment: @MaTaKazer No. Actually, your members should `fetch` the changes from `upstream` and then do a manually `merge`, otherwise, their (local and uncommitted) changes get lost. Give me a second to clarify this in my answer.

The fork _never_ updates to the `upstream` version. You have to get the current version of `upstream` locally and manually `push`it to the fork.

Comment: The forked repo is actually having issue trying to `fetch` updated changes from `upstream` - It just says "All files are up to date." on Android Studio. So I was playing around with all the function over at the github website and concluded with the previous reply.

Comment: @MaTaKazer That's why I wrote, that you and your members should check, whether you try to `pull` or `fetch` from `upstream` or from the `fork`. If you made changes to `upstream` and your team members try to fetch from their fork, then they can't get the changes that were made to `upstream`. The fork is basicly a copy of `upstream`, but they are not bonded together, even though GitHub markes forks as such.

Comment: Alright I am able to rebase my forked repo right now. But I have no idea why my group members can't `push` their update to the forked repo. It keep saying Error 403 as per mentioned on my initial question. I have checked that it is indeed pushing to their forked repo and not the original `upstream`

Comment: @MaTaKazer Have your members entered their correct github credentials (https) or their correct key (ssh)?

Comment: @MaTaKazer Also check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5343146/6774296).

Comment: @I am using Android Studio With Github integration and not using command line. Have checked that I am indeed logged in to the forked repo github account. Not sure if you are familiar with it. If not I could probably try your first suggestion "Same project, different branch" - that sounds a lot simpler

Comment: @MaTaKazer It doesn't matter, whether you are using Android Studio. In the dialog, where you have to put the GitHub URL, you simply add `username@` between `https://` and  `github.com/...`.

Comment: For some reason when I tried to clone the same repo on another computer with also another github account. Somehow I can push to it without any issue. I am very puzzled right now as isn't it suppose to be protected from push from the public?